# IE 10 Enhanced Protection Mode and COM Component Creation class not registered

Tags: internet-explorer, com, activex, internet-explorer-10

I have an ActiveX (AddOn) that runs under IE10. It created using guidelines from the internet and various links. I tried to make it EPM compatible using:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/03/23/understanding-ie10-enhanced-protected-mode-network-security-addons-cookies-metro-desktop.aspx)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn519894(v=vs.85).aspx

- Created both 32 & 64 bit versions of dll
- Registered under Program Files Folder

However, when I try to create a COM component from within this AddOn I get class not registered.
My COM Component is a ActiveX dll and it is created as *INPROC_SERVER*

My *CLSIDFromProgID* call is successful, so there is no issue with registry access in this case. Its the CoCreateInstance which is causing the issue.

```
hr = CLSIDFromProgID(L"myapp.mycontrol", &cls);
if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = CoCreateInstance(cls, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        __uuidof(IMyControl), (void**) &m_pMyCtrl);
    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
      ...
    }
    else {
     Log(hr);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to get this to work? Any pointers on what to look for?

**Update 1:** After further analysing, I see that IE is looking for InprocHandler32 in process monitor.

Why do we need an InProcess Handler for ActiveX that is loaded in process, I thought it is only for Out of Process objects.

Still getting the same issue though.

I'm trying to create an ActiveX that is loaded by IE upon a link of specific MIME type similar to ActiveX Documents, like an MIME Player

[image: This is the error]

Is there a way to find why it is blocking? I get this error even if I won;t create the COM Object.

Comment: It might help to update your question with the exact code you're using that attempts to do the CCI. Also, you might watch for any failures with Process Monitor...

Comment: @EricLaw, thanks a lot for the tip. I updated the question with observations, any tips on finding by the control is blocked? thank you.

Comment: I don't think that prompt is even related to EPM. Do you repro this when EPM is disabled?

Comment: @EricLaw I do't get this when EPM is disabled. Also I notice that white border (Right and Bottom) only in EPM. when its disabled my control gets full window. I Used process of elimination (by removing code, file access etc) to get rid of this prompt, but it does show this prompt all the time in EPM.

Comment: @EricLaw, with your vast experience on IE, any more pointers on where to look for? Also, If I unregister the 64bit binary, I get: 'This web page displays in 'mycontrol'. Do you want to disable Enhanced Protection Mode to run the control? You should only do this if you trust the site' OK, Cancel. Pressing OK load the control, cancel does nothing, Really appreciate all the help. At this moment, I'm running out of Ideas. thanks.